# write an array to .plist file Swift

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I have a function:

```
func saveData (numbertext : String, codetext: String) {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
    let documentDir = paths.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSString
    let path = documentDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("data.plist")
    var dict: NSMutableDictionary = ["name" : "data"]
    //save values
    dict.setObject(numbertext, forKey: data.numberKey)
    dict.setObject(codetext, forKey: data.codeKey)
    dict.writeToFile(path, atomically: false)
}
```

I want to write that array to a .plist file:

```
var tarif : Array<String> = ["first","second","third"]
```

`numbertext` and `codetext` are in another function. How can I write them to an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save it you can simple pass it with

```
dict.setObject (tarif, forKey:...)
```

and retrieving it with

```
tarif = dict.objectForKey(...) as! [String]
```

Comment: tarif = dict.objectForKey(...) as! [String]

you mean's read my an array?

Comment: Exactly. This is the way you get it out of the dictionary later.